# Making list comprehension from 2 columns from a dataframe

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dataframe with 2 columns `name` and `age`

I want to make a list of dictionaries containing their value of `name` and `age` which is like this

```
list = [{'a':'14'}, {'b':'21'}, {'c':'12'}]
```

I've tried using `list = [{i:j} for i,j in df['name'],df['age']]`  but apparently it cannot loop from 2 `for in`. How can I loop the list of dictionaries?

***EDIT***

I have completed it with `list = [{i:j} for i,j in zip(df['name'],df['age'])]`

Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Use `zip`, i.e. `[{i:j} for i,j in zip(df['name'],df['age'])] `.  Also, don't use `list` as a variable name.  It will mask the builtin `list` which you really don't want to do.

Comment: HI thank you for answering, yes the ```zip``` works fine. Thank you @TomKarzes

Comment: @Kenny Aside from that, why do you want to make a list of one-element dictionaries? It is not normally a convenient way to organise your data. The equivalent dictionary `{i:j for i,j in zip(df['name'],df['age'])}` would almost certainly be much more useful.

Comment: even simple like this `dict(zip(df['name'],df['age']))`

Comment: Good point thanks @deadshot

Comment: I am currently using dash in my project and I want to make a list data for other usage :) @alani

Comment: Use this df.to_dict('records')

Comment: @deadshot That produces a different result.  OP wants a list of single-element dicts, not a single flattened dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do that with `zip`. Try: `[{i:j} for i,j in zip(df['name'],df['age'])]`

Comment: hello thank you for the answer. it works :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it works but try this

```
list = [{i:j} for i,j in zip(df['name'],df['age'])]
```